# Distribute MFC42.dll in Windows Setup project in .NET

Tags: .net, visual-c++, deployment, mfc, installation

I have to distribute MFC42.dll in my windows setup project which i am making using .NET. I have to put this file in system folder but getting windows protection error.

Anybody have idea about distribute this file? I can also redistribute vc 6.0 redistributable package but don't know how?

I am using .NET 2008 Setup and Deployment project for this.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You should use the redistributables. Please provide more information on which deployment system you use. InstallShield? ISLE? VCD?

Comment: i tried it but didn't get success in it. It is Setup and Deployment project in .NET 2008.

Answer (score 1):

MFC42.dll is a legacy DLL that's used by lots of Windows programs.  It comes pre-installed in Windows and its *protected* from being replaced by installers.  The feature is called Windows File Protection.  Which is why you got the error.

You should therefore **not** install it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this article will be helpful for you

[Walkthrough: Deploying a Visual C++ Application By Using the Visual C++ Redistributable Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293575.aspx)

You might be interested in ISLE [InstallShield Limited Edition (free for all Visual Studio Users)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/2kt85ked.aspx)